# Zheng Suen thinning algorithm using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, ocr

I have been trying to implement the Zheng-Suen thinning algorithm on MATLAB. My code is running but the results are improper. THe algorithm is being implemented on a binary character.The image is given below. Any sort of help would be appreciated

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmDX5.jpg

```
`I=im2double(I);`        %% I = original image



    [H,W]=size(I);       %% height, width of image


     J=I;                %% J = skeletonized image
     K=I;                %% K = skeletonized image  
     B=0;                %% B = number of non-zero neighbors
     A=0;                %% A = 0-1 patterns
    CHANGE=1000;         %% number of pixels changed over iteration
    P=zeros(8);          %% array to hold the 8-neighborhood values

 %% OUTER LOOP - LOOP UNTIL NO PIXELS CHANGE %%



 while (CHANGE ~= 0)


    CHANGE =0;

    %% FIRST SUB-ITERATION %%

    for r=2:H-1   %% row
    for c=2:W-1   %% column

    if(J(r,c)==1)

    %% find 8 neighborhood of pixel %%

   `P(9) = J(r-1,c-1);  
    P(2) = J(r-1,c);   
    P(3) = J(r-1,c+1);
    P(8) = J(r,c-1);                        
    P(4) = J(r,c+1); 
    P(7) = J(r+1,c-1);  
    P(6) = J(r+1,c);    
    P(5) = J(r+1,c+1);

    %% calculate B %%
    B = P(2)+P(3)+P(4)+P(5)+P(6)+P(7)+P(8)+P(9);

       %% COMPUTE A %%
        A=0;
        if ( P(2)==0   & P(3)==1   )A=A+1; end
        if ( P(3)==0   & P(4)==1   )A=A+1; end 
        if ( P(4)==0   & P(5)==1   )A=A+1; end
        if ( P(5)==0   & P(6)==1   )A=A+1; end
        if ( P(6)==0   & P(7)==1   )A=A+1; end
        if ( P(7)==0   & P(8)==1   )A=A+1; end 
        if ( P(8)==0   & P(9)==1   )A=A+1; end
        if ( P(9)==0   & P(2)==1   )A=A+1; end

        %% DECIDE IF PIXEL SHOULD BE DELETED %%

   if( (B>=2) & (B<=6) & (A==1) & (P(2)*P(4)*P(6)==0) & (P(4)*P(6)*P(8)==0)  )

   K(r,c)=-1;
   CHANGE=CHANGE+1; 
   end
   end
   end
   end


  %% SECOND SUB-ITERATION %%
  J=K;  
for r=2:H-1   %% row
for c=2:W-1   %% column



if(J(r,c)==1)

`P(9) = J(r-1,c-1);  
    P(2) = J(r-1,c);   
    P(3) = J(r-1,c+1);
    P(8) = J(r,c-1);                        
    P(4) = J(r,c+1); 
    P(7) = J(r+1,c-1);  
    P(6) = J(r+1,c);    
    P(5) = J(r+1,c+1);

    B = P(2)+P(3)+P(4)+P(5)+P(6)+P(7)+P(8)+P(9);

        A=0;
        if ( P(2)==0   & P(3)==1   )A=A+1; end
        if ( P(3)==0   & P(4)==1   )A=A+1; end 
        if ( P(4)==0   & P(5)==1   )A=A+1; end
        if ( P(5)==0   & P(6)==1   )A=A+1; end
        if ( P(6)==0   & P(7)==1   )A=A+1; end
        if ( P(7)==0   & P(8)==1   )A=A+1; end 
        if ( P(8)==0   & P(9)==1   )A=A+1; end
        if ( P(9)==0   & P(2)==1   )A=A+1; end    

        %% DECIDE IF PIXEL SHOULD BE DELETED %%

        if( (B>=2) & (B<=6) & (A==1) & (P(2)*P(4)*P(8)==0) & (P(2)*P(6)*P(8)==0)  )
            K(r,c)=-1;
            CHANGE=CHANGE+1;
        end
        end

        end
        end

      CHANGE output # of changes this iteration
      for r=1:H
      for c=1:W
      if(K(r,c)==-1)

         K(r,c)=0;
          end
      end
  end


  figure, imshow(I); figure, imshow(J);
```

`

Answer (score -1):

This is not an answer, but i am unable to comment above. Kindly provide the link to Zheng-Suen thinning algorithm. Also, your code is buggy. Kindly re-post it and any output image also.